# Is there a difference between using requireJS async plugin and requireJS jsonp format

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, requirejs, jsonp

*Using requireJS jsonp format*

```
require( ["jquery", "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Chennai,in&callback=define" ], function( $, weatherData) {

// process stuff

});
```

*Using requireJS async plugin*

```
require( ["jquery", "async!http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Chennai,in" ], function( $, weatherData) {

// process stuff

});
```

1. Does the above code block(s) have the same effect in processing and produce the same result?
2. If they do have the same result, why should we use the async plugin?

Answer (score 0):

1.If the jsonp service is returning an object then yes they produce the same result. However if it is returning an array of data then the define function will use that as a list of dependencies and throw an error. The async plugin will pass the array to your module.

2.The async plugin is also useful when the script you require adds it own additional scripts or performs some setup asynchronously before calling the callback method. Normally requirejs would timeout or return null while waiting for the first script to call define().

Async works around this by creating its own script element and callback function that are not monitored by requirejs.

Comment: Hi.. I understand the diff during runtime.
But since you mentioned the optimization, how is it that the optimiser can inline data with jsonp module. I mean, is it capable doing jsonp calls during build?

Comment: @santhosh-babu I'm not really familiar with the optimiser but you get more information at http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#empty

Comment: @SanthoshBabu I made a mistake with my original answer. I have updated it with some additional information.